# XmlTextWriter not working in my VB .ASP page Literal

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, literals, xmltextwriter

I'm getting the error below when I try usign the XmlTextWriter in my VB aspx page

> Description: An error occurred during
>   the compilation of a resource required
>   to service this request. Please review
>   the following specific error details
>   and modify your source code
>   appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: BC30002: Type
>   'XmlTextWriter' is not defined.

The code I'm using is within the .aspx page inside a <% %> literal

> Dim w As XmlTextWriter = New
>   XmlTextWriter("myxmlfile.xml")

My page header is also like this

> <%@ Page Language="vb"
>   AutoEventWireup="false" Trace="True"
>   EnableViewState="True" %> <%@ Import
>   Namespace="System.Data" %> <%@ Import
>   Namespace="System.Xml" %>

Can anybody explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the MSDN, the XmlTextWriter class is defined in the System.Xml namespace:

[XmlTextWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.aspx)

So, you should add the

Imports System.Xml

directive to the head of the code behind file and also make certain that the System.xml.dll is referenced by your web application.

Comment: Hi DevExpress Team, I'm not using code behind, this is part of a framework that avoids code behind. I'm adding the namespace in the page as `<%@ Import Namespace="System.Xml" %>` and it is still not working, any clue as to why?

Comment: If the System.xml.dll assembly is referenced, you should be able to use the following code:   Dim w As New System.Xml.XmlTextWriter("myxmlfile.xml")

Comment: I think you have an alternative class or namespace named "XML" in your project?

Answer (score 0):

XmlTextWriter actually takes two values, try this...

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Trace="True" EnableViewState="True" %> 
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Xml" %>
<% Dim w As New XmlTextWriter("myxmlfile.xml", System.Text.Encoding.ASCII)%>
```

If that doesn't work, perhaps you have a global XML namespace that is overriting the System.XML class, in which case try

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Trace="True" EnableViewState="True" %> 
<% Dim w As New System.Xml.XmlTextWriter("myxmlfile.xml", System.Text.Encoding.ASCII)%>
```